# Из-за чего может не отрываться сайт на apache через https?

Tags: apache, https, ssl, сертификат

Есть сайт на локальном хостинге.
платформа - **Windows 7**
Сервер - **XAMPP**, включает в себя **Apache/2.4.17**

Купил сертификат **GeoTrust**.

В **httpd.conf** раскомментировал строчки:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
```

В **httpd-ssl.conf** прописал:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLEngine on
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/sitename"
ServerName sitename.ru
ServerAdmin admin@sitename.ru
ErrorLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/access.log"
SSLCertificateFile "c:/xampp/apache/conf/key/domain.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "c:/xampp/apache/conf/key/private.key"
SSLCertificateChainFile "c:/xampp/apache/conf/key/chain.crt"
</VirtualHost>
```

Когда захожу на https://localhost, браузер открывает сайт
Когда захожу по доменному имени https://sitename.ru, то он просто его не находит (Не удается получить доступ). 
Через обычный http всё работает, а через https никак. В чём подвох? Думаю, что шлюз может блокировать 443 порт? Ведь, через локальный ip всё открывается. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решён. На роутере необходимо было пробросить 443 порт.